# messed up partitions: system looks too overload

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

on a notebook with a N 3450 and 500 gb drive i have the following

installed opensuse 42.3 - and i have truely messed up the partitioning.

now i need your help.

especially what i have found out with the following command:

```
linux-jnmx:/home/martin # df -aTh
```

This above mentioned comand gives back some very interesting results. 
The harddrive is being fragmented into many many different small partitions

This is messed up. Now i need to have a clear partition table: with some 
(very few) Partitions. I need to get rid of the many needless partitions.

see the fully gained data:

```
linux-jnmx:/home/martin # fdisk -l
Festplatte /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 Bytes, 976773168 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 6229C7C4-758C-450E-9D59-F59E2AE3CB11


Gerät        Anfang      Ende  Sektoren  Größe Typ
/dev/sda1      2048    321535    319488   156M EFI-System
/dev/sda2    321536   4530175   4208640     2G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sda3   4530176  46475263  41945088    20G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sda4  46475264 976773119 930297856 443,6G Microsoft Basisdaten
linux-jnmx:/home/martin #



inux-jnmx:/home/martin # parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  165MB   164MB   fat16           primary  boot
 2      165MB   2319MB  2155MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary
 3      2319MB  23,8GB  21,5GB  btrfs           primary
 4      23,8GB  500GB   476GB   xfs             primary

Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
Model: hp DVDRAM GU90N (scsi)                                             
Disk /dev/sr0: 4640MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:




linux-jnmx:/home/martin # df -aTh
Dateisystem    Typ             Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
sysfs          sysfs               0       0     0     - /sys
proc           proc                0       0     0     - /proc
devtmpfs       devtmpfs         1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /dev
securityfs     securityfs          0       0     0     - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs          tmpfs            1,9G    360K  1,9G    1% /dev/shm
devpts         devpts              0       0     0     - /dev/pts
tmpfs          tmpfs            1,9G    2,4M  1,9G    1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs            1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore         pstore              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs       efivarfs            0       0     0     - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup         cgroup              0       0     0     - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /
systemd-1      autofs              0       0     0     - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
debugfs        debugfs             0       0     0     - /sys/kernel/debug
mqueue         mqueue              0       0     0     - /dev/mqueue
hugetlbfs      hugetlbfs           0       0     0     - /dev/hugepages
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /srv
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/spool
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /opt
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /.snapshots
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/opt
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/libvirt/images
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/pgsql
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/named
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/mailman
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/tmp
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /tmp
/dev/sda1      vfat             156M    4,6M  152M    3% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/machines
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/crash
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /boot/grub2/i386-pc
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/lib/mariadb
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /usr/local
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/log
/dev/sda3      btrfs             21G    5,8G   14G   30% /var/cache
/dev/sda4      xfs              444G     29G  415G    7% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs            384M     20K  384M    1% /run/user/1000
fusectl        fusectl             0       0     0     - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
gvfsd-fuse     fuse.gvfsd-fuse  0,0K    0,0K  0,0K     - /run/user/1000/gvfs


linux-jnmx:/home/martin #

and last but not least  .....


linux-jnmx:/home/martin # cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3930196 kB
MemFree:          494728 kB
MemAvailable:    2208524 kB
Buffers:            1452 kB
Cached:          1995780 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2148556 kB
Inactive:        1020400 kB
Active(anon):    1172924 kB
Inactive(anon):   126652 kB
Active(file):     975632 kB
Inactive(file):   893748 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:       2104316 kB
SwapFree:        2104316 kB
Dirty:               712 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1171812 kB
Mapped:           378952 kB
Shmem:            127852 kB
Slab:             168164 kB
SReclaimable:     106816 kB
SUnreclaim:        61348 kB
KernelStack:        5952 kB
PageTables:        31652 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4069412 kB
Committed_AS:    3422844 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    333824 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      187136 kB
DirectMap2M:     3891200 kB
linux-jnmx:/home/martin #
```

now i need your help.

especially what i have found out with the following command:

```
linux-jnmx:/home/martin # df -aTh
```

This above mentioned comand gives back some very interesting results. 
The harddrive is being fragmented into many many different small partitions 
This is messed up. Now i need to have a clear partition table: with some 
(very few) Partitions. I need to get rid of the many needless partitions.

Comment: Voted to close. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: uhmmm  - - well i need to clear up the partitioning. Should i edit the question?

Comment: thanks to you davidgo - i have edited the quesion and precided the discourse....

Comment: Still don't understand - what is the problem with your partitioning?

Comment: deaar davidgo - many thanks for your answer: i have issues with the many partitions that i get back with the command # df -aTh  - well so many little partitions are needless. I want to cut down these. I only need a few partitions. What do you say!?

Comment: Don't use the `-a` option. `-a, --all
              include dummy file systems
`. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The harddrive is being fragmented into many many different small partitions

No it isn't.

The  `-a, --all` option means "include dummy file systems"

> -a or -all option include in the listing filesystems that have a size of 0 blocks, which are omitted by default.
>
> Such filesystems are typically special-purpose pseudo-filesystems, such as automounter entries.

Source [What is dummy filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/a/507248/376050), answer by [nux](https://askubuntu.com/users/230052/nux)

And from the comments to that answer:

> [what is the significance of 0 block size for partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507206/what-is-dummy-filesystem#comment684423_507248)
>
> [it means that the "filesystem" doesn't correspond to a physical device. it is purely virtual. examples include e.g. /proc and /sys.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507206/what-is-dummy-filesystem#comment684476_507248)

Comment: hello dear David - many thanks for the answer: Well - can i erase all the so called needless partitions in order to get a tiny little partition-table that is  appropiate!?  I would love to do this via commandline. love to hear from you

Comment: @apollo No you can't erase them. As stated in the answer they are **special-purpose pseudo-filesystems** and are not needless. Just don't use the `-a` option - then you won't see them :)

Comment: man thanks for the answer - now i understand - if i run without a it is clear - and tiny - the set of infos are more clear.. many many thanks for your help